# Grocery crud installation and codeigniter main.php file not working

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

Please help! I'm trying to install grocery crud using codeigniter and I'm using wamp. I can't seem to correct this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to select the specified database: archives_collection
>
> Filename:
>   C:\wamp\www\archives_collection\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 140

The installation documentation says to check the user and password but everything's inputted correctly. However, I'm still getting that error. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

That error happens when it cant find the specific database name, you have to check the database connection and make sure they are correct.. also make sure you have the right permissions for that user.

Comment: Hello! I'm following the installation guideline from the website. I followed every step. How do I edit the permission for the user? Sorry, I'm really new in this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Database name must be set in the config/database.php

Comment: Hi! I already did that but it still doesn't work. Am I missing something?